# Android Material Button is not taking the primary color

Tags: android, material-components-android

The docs about Material Button says:

> For filled buttons, this class uses your theme's ?attr/colorPrimary
>   for the background tint color and ?attr/colorOnPrimary for the text
>   color.

But the Button is taking the Theme accent color. This is my app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

The button code:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="Material button">

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>
```

Colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00574B</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B</color>
</resources>
```

Manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I don't know what I'm missing about the docs.

Comment: Have you verified that you've specified the `AppTheme` style across your app? Could you show us your `colors.xml` file, containing the color/colour definitions for `colorPrimary`? Is the `MaterialButton` a filled button?

Comment: I added the info. Yes, the appTheme is across the app. The MaterialButton is filled by default.

Comment: try to restart and rebuild the project

Comment: Which version of material components library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same issue  with google material library

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
```

I just replaced this library with this

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the confusion. Just apply the style: `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"`

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"                
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:text="Material button">

        </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton>
```